# Why is there no Mardock Scramble full manga online?

Tags: mardock-scramble

Only 6 chapters are available online. Where could I find the rest? Because there's nowhere to be found, and I'm dying to read it.

Answer (score 3):

> Only 6 chapters are available online

Assuming your talking about the English version this is incorrect. [All 7 volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mardock_Scramble#Media) (which if we follow the [pattern here](https://www.mangaupdates.com/releases.html?search=46713&stype=series) would be approximately 21 chapters (3 chapters per volume)) are available in english in both physically format and digital.

on the [Kodansha International site](http://kodanshacomics.com/series/) (which is an American subsidiary of [Kodansha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha)) lists [Mardock Scramble](http://kodanshacomics.com/series/mardock-scramble/) and where you can get all the volumes digitally and physically. each volume lists the same sites (though the links go to the respective volume) but using Volume 1 as an example you can find each volume:

- Digital

  - [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DN7BFE2)
  - [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/id1029766387)
  - [Barnes & Noble](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/mardock-scramble-1-tow-ubukata/1102622264;jsessionid=017936A7C017A9C80659A7EEFD441844.prodny_store01-atgap01?ean=9781612625270)
  - [Kobo](https://www.kobo.com/au/en/ebook/mardock-scramble-14)
  - [Comixology](https://www.comixology.com/Mardock-Scramble-Vol-1/digital-comic/272063)
- Physical

  - [Penguin Publishing House](http://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/212633/mardock-scramble-1-by-created-by-tow-ubukata-manga-by-yoshitoki-oima/9781935429531)

i greatly suspect that the reason why you can only find 6 chapters online is because you are looking for the scanlation which stopped at chapter 6 in 2011, the same year the manga was licensed in English. we won't post links to scalations here on Anime and Manga Stack Exchange nor should you be looking for them when a series has been officially licensed in your language as this is then piracy